# Ehcache: two different CacheManagers configured to use different folders but actually use the same

Tags: java, ehcache

We have a tool that deals with objects coming from two different, complex sources.  The internal structure of these sources and the objects they hold are similar.  The sources can be identified by a short string, say A and B.

We cache the objects using Ehcache.  The objects from different sources need to be kept separate. Because of the complexity and similarity of the two sources, this separation is done by using two different CacheManagers with different cache paths. Our expectation is that objects of source A are stored in, e.g., `[base folder]/cache.A` and those of source B in `[base folder]/cache.B`.

We setup the cache managers with a common `ehcache.xml` file, which is referred to by its URL.  Each cache manager is then referred to by its sourceId.

```
URL ehcacheXML = getClass().getResource("/ehcache.xml");
Configuration config = ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ehcacheXML);
DiskStoreConfiguration diskConfig = config.getDiskStoreConfiguration(); 
diskConfig.setPath([base folder] + "/cache." + sourceId);
CacheManager manager = CacheManager.create(config);
```

The problem is that only one of the folders is created, e.g., `cache.A`.  Any access goes to this folder, regradless whether it is via a cache held by the cache manager for A or the one for B.

For example, assume I want to access the cached objects for `objectName` for both sources.  For each of the sources, they are stored in a cache with name `cacheName`.  Then `cacheManagerA.getCache(cacheName).get(objectName)` accesses the same Element as `cacheManagerB.getCache(cacheName).get(objectName)`. Surprisingly, `cacheManagerA.getCache(cacheName).getGuid()` and `cacheManagerB.getCache(cacheName).getGuid()` differ and `cacheManagerA` and `cacheManagerB` are different (have different hash codes), too.

I tried to create the cache managers with `newInstance()` instead of `create()` but that did not solve the issue.

Comment: Will need the Ehcache version in order to give the exact answer. But as its javadoc states, `CacheManager.create` is to be used when you want a singleton `CacheManager`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: Two changes are required:

- assign a new name to each instance, e.g.,  with `config.setName(sourceId)`
- use `newInstance(config)` instead of `create(config)`

Without the first point, calling `newInstance()` will always return the same instance, similar to `create()`.